# locking a pc using keyEvents

Tags: java

I want to lock my pc when my java application runs, so I used Robot class to implement a combination of two keys: windows logo key + L. But it didn't work!
here is my code:

```
Robot a=new Robot();  
a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);  
a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The keys would need to be interrupted by the OS.  The keys are sent to the currently focused component.  You might like to take a look at [this](http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna) instead

Comment: But why this code works for KeyEvent.VK_D that shows the desktop and for KeyEvent.VK_E that opens my computer window ?!

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB The OS may be interrupting the key press directly from the keyboard driver instead to prevent this...possibly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet in your listener class to lock screen in windows machines.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation");
```